# Microsoft Graph API の Applications API servicePrincipals の preferredSingleSignOnMode プロパティ仕様の最新情報について

Tags: microsoft-graph

Microsoft Graph API の Applications API のservicePrincipals一覧の中の [preferredSingleSignOnMode プロパティ](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0)仕様の最新情報を知りたいです。

#### 質問

2020 年初頭以前に作成されたアプリでは、SAML を構成していても preferredSingleSignOnMode が nullになるという状況に変化はないでしょうか？

#### 目的

SAML を構成しているアプリ一覧を取得したいです。
preferredSingleSignOnMode が null にならず値がセットされることを期待しています。

#### 確認したこと

2023/7/14最終更新の以下記事を確認しました。
https://jpazureid.github.io/blog/azure-active-directory/get-certificates-secrets-expirydateandtime/

> 2020 年初頭 (1 ～ 3 月) 以降に作成されたアプリのみ
> SAML を構成した際に preferredSingleSignOnMode に 値がセットされる動作になりました。
> そのため、2020 年初頭以前に作成されたアプリでは、
> 現在、SAML を構成していても preferredSingleSignOnMode が null となっております。
> 2020 年初頭以前に作成されたアプリの場合、
> PowerShell や Graph API などで SAML を構成していると判別できる値を取得することができず、
> SAML を構成しているアプリ一覧として取得することが難しい状況となります。
> 将来的には、古いアプリにおいても新しいアプリと同様に
> 正しい preferredSingleSignOnMode が取得できるようになることが計画されていることを確認しましたが、
> 対応時期などは未定です